# How inline nested fuction in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, callback

Consider example with Angular `$resource` and `SpringDataRestAdapter` from `angular-spring-data-rest`:

```
var resource = $resource("url/:id", {id: '@id'}, {query: {method: 'GET', isArray: false}});

$scope.questionary.query({}, function callback(data) {
    SpringDataRestAdapter.process(data).then(function (processedResponse) {
    }
});
```

`SpringDataRestAdapter.process` has the same semantic as `callback`.

How to pass `SpringDataRestAdapter.process` instead of `callback` with chained `then` call?

**UPDATED**

Rewrote question with real world example.

Comment: What parts of your second example are variable? It's very hard to tell what you're asking here.

Comment: Chained calls work when the method does `return this;`, thus returning the same `MyUtilityObject`.  That lets you keep calling methods on that object.

Comment: So, you're trying to pass a callback to `myObject.myFunc`? Or...? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Question updated. Provided real word example.

Comment: Ah!  I think I see now what you are trying to do.  You can't do that.  You need to pass a *function* to `query()` as its callback.  You could pass `SpringDataRestAdapter.process`, sure (it may need to be `SpringDataRestAdapter.process.bind(SpringDataRestAdapter)`), but you couldn't then chain other methods.  `SpringDataRestAdapter.process(data)` returns an object, not a function.  Plus, `data` wouldn't exist at that point.  The way you have it is the correct way.